# Given two sets, is there a formula to know the quantity of injective function realationships?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, combinations

For example.

\begin{align*}
&A\quad =\quad \{ 1,2\} \\ 
&B\quad =\quad \{ a,b\} \\
&\texttt{Then 2 injective functions from } A\rightarrow B \\ 
&\left\{ (1,a),(2,b) \right\} \quad \{ (1,b),(2,a)\}  \\ \\
&A\quad =\quad \{ 1,2\} \\ 
&B\quad =\quad \{ a,b,c\} \\
&\texttt{Then 6 injective functions from } A\rightarrow B \\ 
&\left\{ (1,a),(2,b) \right\} \quad \{ (1,a),(2,c)\} \quad \\ 
&\{ (1,b),(2,a)\} \quad \{ (1,b),(2,c)\} \\ 
&\{ (1,c),(2,a)\} \quad \{ (1,c),(2,b)\} \\ \\
&A\quad =\quad \{ 1,2,3\} \\ 
&B\quad =\quad \{ a,b,c\} \\
&\texttt{Then 12 injective functions from } A\rightarrow B \\ 
&\left\{ (1,a) (2,b) (3,a) \right\} 
\left\{ (1,a) (2,b) (3,c) \right\}\\ 
&\left\{ (1,a) (2,c) (3,a) \right\} 
\left\{ (1,a) (2,c) (3,b) \right\}\\ 
&\left\{ (1,b) (2,a) (3,b) \right\} 
\left\{ (1,b) (2,a) (3,c) \right\}\\ 
&\left\{ (1,b) (2,c) (3,a) \right\} 
\left\{ (1,b) (2,c) (3,b) \right\}\\ 
&\left\{ (1,c) (2,a) (3,b) \right\} 
\left\{ (1,c) (2,a) (3,c) \right\}\\ 
&\left\{ (1,c) (2,b) (3,a) \right\} 
\left\{ (1,c) (2,b) (3,c) \right\}\\ 
\end{align*}

Comment: You may be interested to reference [Stanley's Twelvefold Way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way), where this and related questions are tabulated.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's not really fair to call it "Stanley's Twelvefold Way".

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I've heard it referred to as such in a number of settings[1](http://www.johndcook.com/TwelvefoldWay.pdf)[2](http://arxiv.org/ftp/math/papers/0606/0606404.pdf) (he was Rota's student as I understand).  Even so, it isn't always referred to as such, so I suppose I can see your point.

Comment: The function $\{(1,a) (2,b) (3,a)\}$ is not injective as it maps 1 and 3 to the same point. If A and B have 3 members each then there are just 6 injections from A to B.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Typo. So your saying my first and second examples are not true?

Comment: Thank you. I found my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty, finite sets such that $A$ has at most as many elements as $B$. Let $m$ be the number of elements in $A$ and let $n$ be the number of elements in $B$. WLOG assume that $A = \{ 1, 2, \ldots, m \}$ and $B = \{1, 2, \ldots, n \}$. Then there are precisely $\binom{n}{m} \cdot m!$ many injections $A \to B$.

To see this, let $[B]^m$ be the set of all subsets of $B$ with $m$ elements. And let $S_m$ be the permutation group on $m$ elements. Let $\mathcal F$ the the set of all injections $A \to B$. Then

$$\pi \colon \mathcal F \to [B]^m \times S_m, f \mapsto (\operatorname{im}(f), f^*)$$

is a bijection, where $f^* \colon m \to m$ is the unique permutation such that for all $x,y \in \{1, \ldots, m\}$ we have $x < y$ iff $f \circ f^*(x) < f \circ f^*(y)$.

Since $[B]^m$ has $\binom{n}{m}$ many elements and $S_m$ has $m!$ many elements, the result follows.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that $\binom{n}{m}\cdot m!$ can simplify as $n^{\underline{m}} = P(n,m) = ~_nP_m = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$, depending on your preferred notation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's a 'nicer' way to define $f^*$ - I think of it as the unique permutation such that $f \circ f^*(1) < f \circ f^* (2) < \ldots < f \circ f^*(m)$.